# Error while running jest on node 0.12.0

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to run Jest test in my project and I have node v0.12.0 , so running the Jest test gives me the error below:

> /Users/ajaybeniwal203/ODeskWork/ui-components/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/harmonize/harmonize.js:31
>           node.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
>
> **TypeError:** Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
>       at module.exports (*/Users/ajaybeniwal203/ODeskWork/ui-components/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/harmonize/harmonize.js:31:20*)
>
> at `Object.<anonymous>` (*/Users/ajaybeniwal203/ODeskWork/ui-components/node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js:39:1*)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
>
> at startup (node.js:129:16)
>
> at node.js:814:3 npm ERR! Test failed.
>
> See above for more details.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is known [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/243):

> It's known and has to do with JSDOM + contextify mostly.

Try using node 0.10 instead, [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) or similar alternatives available for windows should help.

Answer (score 1):

Cool Question. This is due to Jest does NOT support Node v0.12

Unfortunately, there is NO way to resolve this so far (jest v0.4.x); however, here is workaround: Use v0.10

Try to use nvm to switch node version for your development env:

## Switch to previous version

`nvm use 0.10`

## Rebuild dependencies

`npm rebuild`

## Run tests on previous version

`npm test`

FYI, if you use Node, the next version of Jest (v0.5) will NOT support; if you use io.js, it's all good to continue.

I have using Jest since v0.1 and sorry to say that I have 0 confidence on it anymore. I will switch to Mocha then.

HTH